# Check for match before adding to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an empty array that will be recieving compound objects upon a button click. I'm trying to generate a random url to be assigned to each, but only if the url hasn't been used previously.

The confusing part is that I cannot check against an empty array, so I have to write a condition at the beginning that says if the array is empty, add the url. I can't seem to get this to work so if anyone could help, I would appreciate it! Thanks in advance.

```
var pets = [];

var petPics = ["http://cdn2-..", etc]

this.getPetPic = function() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * petPics.length);
    if (pets[0] === "undefined") {
        return petPics[random];
    } else {
        for (var pet of pets) {
            if (petPics[random] != pet.image) {
                return petPics[random];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ---Forget your code for a second--- Your code is really confusing. Can you try to explain your question better please? Why can't you check against an empty array?

Comment: use `pets.length === 0` instead of `pets[0] === "undefined"` or change it to `typeof pet[0] === 'undefined'`

Comment: why do you use those loops and not `indexOf()`? And why do you check for the string "undefined"?